# SendMessage gives ACCESS DENIED error when trying to send from IE process

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, winsock-lsp

I'm working on a Download Manager and I'm writing an LSP for browser integration. It works perfectly on every browser except IE.
When I try to communicate with my application process using `SendMessage` API, it fails with error 5 (Access Denied). When I try to attach the debugger to `iexplore.exe`, Visual Studio shows that this process is running with *[low-rights]*. What can I do now?
IE uses this process for working with the sockets and I have to be able to communicate with my download manager process.

Comment: Hi Javid. It seems that IE 11 broke LSP compatibility as Windows 8 did in Metro.

Comment: So I gotta write a WSP for that, right?

Comment: I think so. And that's not an easy task.

Comment: I suppose it's easier than LSP which I've already written!